# Angular 2 service property values undefined in my lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have several properties in a service that I would like to share in other lazy loaded modules

My service is defined as:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {

  private _deviceId: string;
  private _accountId: string;

  constructor() { }

  initialise(): Promise<any> {


    if(this.getDeviceIDFromLocalStorage() && this.getAccountIDFromLocalStorage()) {
      return Promise.resolve(ErrorCode.EXISTING_USER);
    } 

  }

  setApplicationId(applicationId): void {
    this._deviceId = applicationId;
  }

  getApplicationId(): string {
    return this._deviceId;
  }

  setAccountId(accountId): void {
    this._accountId = accountId;
  }

  getAccountId(): string {
    if(typeof this._accountId !== 'undefined') {
      return this._accountId;
    } else {
      return '0';
    }
  }


  public getDeviceIDFromLocalStorage(): Boolean {
    let deviceID = localStorage.getItem(appkeys.DEVICE_ID);

    if((typeof deviceID !== 'undefined') && (deviceID !== null)){
      this.setApplicationId(deviceID);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public getAccountIDFromLocalStorage(): Boolean {
    let accountId = localStorage.getItem(appkeys.ACCOUNT_ID);

    if((typeof accountId !== 'undefined') && (accountId !== null)){
      this.setAccountId(accountId);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }



}
```

And I declare the service in a shared module

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LogoComponent } from './logo.component';
import { AppSettingsService } from './app-settings.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LogoComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    LogoComponent
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ AppSettingsService ]
    }
  }
}
```

All the data loads fine in the core app. When I navigate to a different lazy loaded module, and call getApplicationId() or getAccountId() the properties _deviceId and _accountId are undefined.

in my lazy loaded module, I import the shared module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
<excluded for clarity>

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [
    <excluded for clarity>

  ],
  providers: [
    <excluded for clarity>

  ]
})
export class AdvertisementModule { }
```

In my component, I import the service

```
import { AppSettingsService } from '../shared/app-settings.service’;
```

and reference it in the constructor

```
constructor(private _router: Router, private _appService: AppSettingsService) { }
```

What am I missing or is it not possible to persist values in the service in this way? I'm using angular-cli webpack 2.1.0-beta.25

Comment: why angularjs tag and angular-cli tag ? don't put tag randomly. And your example is too big. reduce if you can.

Comment: If you're calling `.forRoot` in every module, you're explicitly creating multiple instances of the shared module. I'd suggest a read through https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe